# How does this integral converge towards zero as R approaches ∞?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, trigonometry, convergence-divergence

I am struggling to understand how that, for the integral below, the result is 0 as R tends to infinity.

[integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbeBa.png)

I've tried re-arranging the integrand to make sense of it but I haven't gotten far with this. Does anyone know how to approach an integral of this form when taking limits of R?

Thank you for your time

Comment: $$\left|\int_0^{\pi}f(\theta)d\theta\right|\leq \int_0^{\pi}\left|f(\theta)\right|d\theta$$ This removes the $\exp(i R \cos(\theta))$ part and you are left with $\exp(-R\sin(\theta))$ in the integrand

Comment: You can then estimate the r.h.s. by splitting up the integral, replacing $\sin(\theta)$ near the limits where it zero by a linear function. The idea is then that the integral in the large R limit will only get a contribution from a region of size 1/R , therefore it will tend to zero as 1/R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\verts{\ic\int_{0}^{\pi}\expo{\ic R\cos\pars{\theta} - R\sin\pars{\theta}}\,\,\,\,\,\dd\theta}} \leq
\int_{0}^{\pi}\expo{- R\sin\pars{\theta}}\,\,\dd\theta
\\[5mm] = & \
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\expo{- R\cos\pars{\theta}}\,\,\dd\theta =
2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\expo{- R\cos\pars{\theta}}\,\,\dd\theta
\\[5mm] = & \
2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\expo{- R\sin\pars{\theta}}\,\,\dd\theta \leq
2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\expo{- 2R\theta/\pi}\,\,\dd\theta
\\[5mm] & =
\pi\,{1 - \expo{-R} \over R}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ R\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\, \bbx{\pi \over R} \\ &
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you Felix, this helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

$$I(R)=i\int_0^\pi e^{iR\cos(x)-R\sin(x)}dx=i\int_0^\pi e^{iR\left(\cos(x)+i\sin(x)\right)}dx=i\int_0^\pi e^{iRe^{ix}}dx$$
$u=e^{ix}$ so $dx=\frac{du}{iu}$ so:
$$I(R)=-\int_{-1}^1\frac{e^{iRu}}{u}du$$
$$I'(R)=-i\int_{-1}^1e^{iRu}du=-\left[\frac{e^{iRu}}{R}\right]_{-1}^1=-\frac{e^{iR}-e^{-iR}}{R}=-\frac{2\sinh(R)}{R}$$
and from this we could calculate:
$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\left[-\frac{2\sinh(R)}{R}\right]$$
and you could use this to help answer your question